# Can EJB entities be used as value objects?

Tags: java, ejb

I usually have one value object for each entity bean. I populate the value object reading the entity bean in the database layer, and send the value object to the business and presentation layers.

The objective is to send value objects among the three layers.

My issue is twofold: (1) I have to maintain the value object every time I change the entity bean, and (2) if the entity bean has other related entity beans, I have to read all of them into the value object - thus not taking advantage of lazy loading.

What if I use the entity bean itself as the value object? I wouldn't need to maintain fields twice, I wouldn't need to populate any value objects, and would fully utilize lazy loading. My issue there is that I would be sending an entity bean to the presentation layer, and that doesn't seem right.

What is the best practice and the best way to go?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I inject the EntityManager in the Stateless/Statefull session bean, lazy loading the value object as needed taking the information from the entity bean. Then pass the value object to the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of about the same. Sending entity bean directly to the presentation layer from a session bean.
However that doesn't seem to be right approach because once a entity bean is serialized it's lazy loaded properties would be inaccessible. So every time you transport your entity bean you have to make sure you get the lazy loaded properties before returning it to presentation layer(before transportation).